# Appears to run from boot but buttons (controlling GPIO music box) don't work as they do when I run from desktop

Tags: python

Following Raspberry Pi's "GPIO music box" toutorial I've made a little script that plays voice recordings when a button is pushed on a modded SNES controller.
It runs fine from desktop (through Python IDLE) but not from boot.

I've used "sudo nano /etc/rc.local" to add the line "@reboot python /home/pi/gpio-music-box/omas_voice.py &" before the "exit 0" line.
This causes my debug text (the false loading message) to be displayed but the buttons still don't work as they do when I run the program through the Python 3 (IDLE) program.

Edit:
If I load the desktop with "startx" and run the command "idle -r omas_voice.py" the program runs fine and the buttons play the sounds but if I try to run the same command from the command line (without fist booting the desktop environment)
I get these errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/idle", line5, in "<"moduel">"
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1553, in main root = TK(className="Idle")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/TKinter.py", line 1823, in __ init __ self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, classNAme, interactive, wantobjects, useTK, sync, use)_tinker.Tc1Error: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

```
print ("Oma's Voice is Starting Please wait...")
print ("Loading: 10%")
print ("Loading: 20%")
print ("Loading: 30%")
print ("Loading: 40%")
print ("Loading: 50%")
print ("Loading: 60%")
print ("Loading: 70%")
print ("Loading: 80%")
print ("Loading: 90%")


import pygame
from gpiozero import Button

pygame.init()

btn_left        =   Button(5)
btn_right       =   Button(6)
btn_l_shoulder  =   Button(12)
btn_r_shoulder  =   Button(13)
btn_start       =   Button(16)
brtn_select     =   Button(17)

left            =   pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/gpio-music-box/left_button.wav")
right           =   pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/gpio-music-box/right_button.wav")
l_shoulder      =   pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/gpio-music-box/left_shoulder.wav")
r_shoulder      =   pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/gpio-music-            box/right_shoulder.wav")
start           =   pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/gpio-music-box/start_button.wav")
select          =   pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/gpio-music-box/select_button.wav")

btn_left        .when_pressed   =   left        .play
btn_right       .when_pressed   =   right       .play
btn_l_shoulder  .when_pressed   =   l_shoulder  .play
btn_r_shoulder  .when_pressed   =   r_shoulder  .play
btn_start       .when_pressed   =   start       .play
brtn_select     .when_pressed   =   select      .play

print ("Loading: 100%")
print ("Oma's Voice has loaded. Enjoy!  :D")
print ("Please report bugs and submit requests to Michael")
```

Expected buttons attached to the GPIO pins of my Raspberry Pi (5,6,12,13,16,17) to play a recorded .wav file when pressed. 
My "Oma's Voice is Starting Please wait..." debug messages are displayed on boot so it appears that the program is working but when I push the buttons no sound is played.